# git and hudson/jenkins - how to do incremental builds only?

Tags: git, hudson

How would I configure hudson/jenkins to checkout only the files/submodules,etc.. that have changed since the last nightly build?
In our build system(ant/ivy), if it is checked out it gets built.  So, I need to only checkout what has changed in order to do an incremental build.

Answer (score 1):

Thats the default behaviour with the git plugin unless you set the project to do a clean build. What have you set up for it NOT to work?

Comment: really?  I have not setup anything special.  We let git populate the workspace with default settings.  It seems to checkout everything.

Comment: at the first run yes .. but subsequentially it will only do a pull .. which will get the changes only unless you specified to have the project workspace cleaned up after each run..