# how to make jenkins use an already checked out codebase?

Tags: jenkins

I am just starting with `Jenkins 1.487` and wanted to integrate Jenkins in my Ant project. But while configuring it, I can't find any way to make Jenkins re-use an already checked out codebase, instead of downloading a fresh copy relative to its workspace root. Is there a way to do that ?

I tried to specify a custom workspace manually (where my codebase was already checked out), and clicked on 'Build now'. The result was that it wiped out my current checked out code saying

```
"Checking out a fresh workspace because there's no workspace at /home/daud/Work
Cleaning local Directory ."
```

Not even a warning..

Comment: What you are referring to is an "incremental build". afaik this differs depending on the version control system you use. When using git, doing an incremental build is the default. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383136/git-and-hudson-jenkins-how-to-do-incremental-builds-only). What VCS are you using?

Comment: I am using SVN.. when I tried to specify a manual workspace (where code already exists), it said that "Checking out a fresh workspace because there's no workspace at /home/daud/Work
Cleaning local Directory ." and wiped out my old code :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really want to build from an existing checkout somewhere on the file system, then do not use "Source Code Management" section of Jenkins. Leave it as **"none"**

- Go straight to the **"Build"** section
- Click "Add Build Step"
- Select Invoke Ant"
- Click Advanced
- And under "Build File", provide a full path to the ant build file on your file system. You would have to include the drive letter (if on Windows) or a leading / (if on Linux) to break from the Workspace (by default, this path is relative to Workspace). Or use a lot of ../../../.. if needed.

But like others have said, this is not the way a CI system is supposed to be used

Comment: Thanks.. I just want to reuse the existing build (there are local changes on each server that're specific to that server, and if I check out a new build, I'll have to make those local changes again). I want SVN updates to happen (so Source code management can't be none)

Comment: You've really got to clarify your question. You want SVN updates? You want Hudson to perform SVN update? If not, i've given you the solution. If you do want Hudson to perform SVN updates, then set it up as such. What "local changes" exist on each server that are not in SVN checkout? Are these unversioned files? If so, Hudson SVN update will ignore unversioned files unless you tell it to use "revert" or "fresh checkout". If they are versioned, and modified, they would behave the same when doing SVN update from Hudson or otherwise (they would be merged with latest changes)

Comment: Once you let Hudson do the initial checkout, you can then perform SVN operations on the Hudson's workspace's checkout folder as required. It won't be deleting it everytime, unless your SVN URL changes

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind Jenkins and CI is that it works on a *fresh* copy of the codebase. Every build done by Jenkins should *not* depend on any external preconditions and it should be reproducible.

Comment: I was just trying to avoid downloading the entire project again.. is it anyhow possible ?

Comment: Once you download the entire project once, it will only look for changes (unless you change the "Check-out Strategy" to do a fresh checkout every time). It well worth the one-time cost of checking out

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using the [Clone Workspace SCM Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Clone+Workspace+SCM+Plugin) for Jenkins. It will allow you to zip up the workspace from one job and use it to create the workspace for another one. I've used this for downstream jobs that need to act on the work from a previous job.

This is also helpful if you're using something like Git for source control and want to avoid a second Git clone (or SVN checkout). Furthermore, you can limit the content of zip file that is used to recreate the workspace, for example to avoid carrying unnecesary files (e.g. the `.git` or `.svn` directories) downstream.